# C++ async return value different when using x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit, stdasync

The following Code compiles using both Debug\Win32 and Debug \ **x64** settings in VC2013, but when I use Debug \ **x64** i get the following **IntelliSense Error**:

```
    IntelliSense: no operator "=" matches these operands
    operand types are: std::future<bar<int>> = std::future<bar<int> (&)(bar<int> v)>
```

The Error refers to this function in Header.cpp:

```
bar<int> test::call(bar<int> v)
{
    std::future<bar<int>> ret;
    ret = std::async(std::launch::async, &test::exec, this, v);

    return ret.get();
}
```

Why does std::async return something diffrent when using x64?

return value win32:

```
std::future<bar<int>>
```

return value x64:

```
std::future<bar<int> (&)(bar<int>
```

How can i fix this for x64?

---

My Code:

Header.h

```
#pragma once
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class bar
{
public:
    bar()
    {
        state = 9;
    }

    void dec(){ state--; }

    T show()
    {
        return state;
    }

private:
    T state;
};



class test{
public:
    test(int a);

public:
    bar<int> call(bar<int> v);

private:
    bar<int> exec(bar<int> v);




private:
    int value;
};
```

Header.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"


using namespace std;


test::test(int a)
{
    value = a;
}

bar<int> test::call(bar<int> v)
{
    std::future<bar<int>> ret;
    ret = std::async(std::launch::async, &test::exec, this, v);

    return ret.get();
}

bar<int> test::exec(bar<int> v)
{
    v.dec();
    v.dec();
    return v;
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;   

int main()
{
    test object(4);
    bar<int> foo;
    bar<int> other = object.call(foo);
    std::cout << other.show();
    getchar();
}
```

**Edit:**
I do not want to use auto, because auto would not work in other scenarios (for example creating a vector of futures and then pushing back futures)

This Error is **NOT** a **compiler error**, the code compiles and executes flawlesly ==> i can't post the compiler error because there is no compiler error. I just want to get rid of the VC IntelliSense Error

Using std::move() does not solve the problem, i still get an IntelliSense Error:
(The Code compiles and executes perfectly with and without the use of std::move)

```
IntelliSense: no operator "=" matches these operands
            operand types are: std::future<bar<int>> = std::future<bar<int> (&)(bar<int> v)>
```

Comment: Post the real compiler error or warning, not Intellisense messages.

Comment: what about `auto ret = std::async( .... );`

Comment: You probably have to use `std::move`.