# C++: VS IntelliSense and the return value of std::async

Tags: visual-studio-2013, return-value, intellisense, stdasync

I have a piece of code which uses `std::async`. This is the function I call via `async`:

```cpp
cv::Mat CtVolume::prepareProjection(size_t index, FilterType filterType) const
```

As one can see, it's return value is `cv::Mat`.

Now somewhere in my code I declare a variable for the return of the `async` call like this:

```cpp
std::future<cv::Mat> future;
```

And at some other point the actual call looks like this:

```cpp
future = std::async(std::launch::async, &CtVolume::prepareProjection, this, projection + 1, filterType);
```

Now, in this line IntelliSense underlines the equality sign and displays the following error message:

```cpp
IntelliSense: no operator "=" matches these operands 
operand types are: std::future<cv::Mat> = std::future<cv::Mat (&)(unsigned long long, ct::FilterType)
```

However, the code compiles and runs fine. Now, is this just an IntelliSense issue or should I declare my return value somehow differently? IDE is Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652485/c-async-return-value-different-when-using-x64